# Is there any intuitive explanation for MoM in estimating parameters?

Tags: estimation, extreme-value, method-of-moments

I found from some [literature](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4rfLa5ev7AhWgmnIEHfHZBDgQFnoECC0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fminerva.it.manchester.ac.uk%2F%7Esaralees%2Fbook5.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Zu4vdvAy1Xsiq09-EZDFn) that when we use the method of moments to fit the Gumbel distribution, the estimated[image]

[image]

> (On page 24) A comparison of the variance formulas in (1.66) with the CramBr-Rao lower bounds in (1.61) readily  reveals that the moment estimator ii has about 95% efficiency while the moment estimator 6 has only about 55% efficiency.

Why is MoM so efficient in estimating the first parameter but only 55% efficient in estimating the second parameter? Is there any intuitive explanation for this? Is it because the Gumbel distribution is skewed to the left with respect to the normal distribution, so the second-order moments are not accurate?

Comment: Skewness of itself is not necessarily dispositive of why some moment estimator is efficient or inefficient; after all the sample mean is efficient for estimating the population mean of an exponential, and it's efficient when estimating the population mean of a normal.

Comment: @Glen_b So is there any other explanation for that?

Comment: An explanation for why an estimator is efficient/not? Inefficient estimators fail to use all the information in the data; an efficient estimator will show some difference from it in the way the data are used. A simple example with a MoM estimator would be the sample mean for the population mean of a Laplace-distributed random variable. Loosely, the sample mean puts too much weight on the tails and too little weight on the middle. A second example would be the uniform on $(\mu-\theta,\mu+\theta)$; here the sample mean puts too much weight in the center when it better to put it on the extremes.

Comment: @Glen_b How about my case the Gumbel distribution?